# Como crear login para distintos tipos de usuarios en laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, login, users-roles

Hola buenas tengo una duda, estoy trabajando en un sistema de intranet para una escuela en la cual tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se puede ver tengo varios tipos de usuarios y cada uno tiene su modelo y controlador con sus metodos (index,crear,ver,delete,etc). Mi pregunta es si puedo crear un login para cada uno de estos tipos de usuario y limitarle funciones y vistas según corresponda ?? ya que cuando busco metodos de auth siempre usan como base la tabla users de laravel. Ya que quiero iniciar sesion por ej con un alumno y quiero que este vea solo sus notas, datos, etc... Alguien sabe que puedo hacer al respecto ?

[GitHub](https://github.com/erickleal/sisLiceoo)

Comment: Hola! yo no creo que sea necesario hacer login distintos para cada tipo de usuario, hay muchos plugins para laravel que te ayudan a crear `Roles` para cada usuario, con distintos tipos de permisos para ciertas funciones.. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/roles-and-permissions-in-laravel-5

Comment: La respuesta es: sí, puedes crear login diferentes para cada tipo de usuario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te recomiendo, que el login sea el mismo para todos. Pero cada usuario lo vas a manejar por roles. Entonces al ingresar un usuario con Role administrador, va ver mas vistas y funcionalidades del sistema que uno tipo alumno.

En tus tablas, alumnos, administrativos y profesor tenes muchos campos en comun. Podes simplificar todos en una tabla que sea usuario por ejemplo y con un campo tipo que defina si es profesor, alumno etc.

Lo siguiente es como manejo yo los roles en un sistema que tiene distintos tipos de usuarios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Laravel utiliza las etiquetas @can..@endcan para filtrar vistas y esto se realiza utilizando el metodo BOOT que se encuentra en AuthServiceProvider.php dentro de la carpeta Providers, dentro de carpeta app.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, consulta, eso de roles y permisos lo usas con algun package?? si no es asi tienes algun tutorial para seguir?? te agradeceria la respuesta soy nuevo en laravel

Comment: No, lo hice yo nomas. No se como podrias contactarme por email o nose y te explico o paso codigo.

Comment: Hola disculpa la tardanza, si me gustaria que me mostraras el proyecto en estos momentos igual estoy usando un pakage Entrust que viene con roles y permisos en laravel te dejo mi correo eleal.escobar@gmail.com y lo que llevo de proyecto https://github.com/erickleal/sjb-1.0